# What to do, If a variable inside an foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php, foreach

This is my code:

```
$recommendations_name_list = explode(',',$result[$x]["recommendations_title"]);
$recommendations_vote_average = explode(',',$result[$x]["recommendations_vote_average"]);


foreach( $recommendations_name_list as $index => $recommendations_title ) {
           echo'<p>'.$recommendations_title.'</p>
                <p>'.$recommendations_vote_average[$index].'</p>';
}
```

Now, If in the  9th loop`$recommendations_title` have some value but  `$recommendations_vote_average[$index]` do not have a value. Then I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 9

Comment: it just says that your second variable is not as long as your first variable (the one you used for the foreach)

Comment: check the value or array is set

Comment: Hey Josh, haven't read your question yet, but I already want to point out that your question's title is pretty bad. What to do if there is a variable inside a foreach loop? It really doesn't say anything.

Comment: Check your array with `var_dump($recommendations_name_list); var_dump($recommendations_vote_average)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if that key isset in your second array before echo it because you can't echo a value that is not set.

```
$recommendations_name_list = explode(',',$result[$x]["recommendations_title"]);
$recommendations_vote_average = explode(',',$result[$x]["recommendations_vote_average"]);


foreach( $recommendations_name_list as $index => $recommendations_title ) {
    echo'<p>'.$recommendations_title.'</p>';

    if(isset($recommendations_vote_average[$index])){

        echo '<p>'.$recommendations_vote_average[$index].'</p>';
    }else{
        echo '<p>No value</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: it still gives the error + nothing echo now

Comment: @JoshPoor check edited answer please.